# binary gcd algorithm - not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, greatest-common-divisor

I read the binary gcd algorithm and tried to implement it .It worked. This is my code

```
int gcd2(int a, int b) {
   int sh;

   if (a == 0)
        return b;
   if (b == 0)
        return a;

   for (sh = 0; !((a | b) & 1); sh++) {
      a >>= 1;
      b >>= 1;
   }

   while (!(a & 1)) {
      a >>= 1;
   }

    while(b) {
      while (!(b & 1)) {
          b >>= 1;
      }

      if (a > b) {
          int t = a;
          a = b;
          b = t;
      }

      b = b - a;
   }

   return a << sh;
}
```

But doesn't work if I replace the last if with

```
    if (b > a)
    {
        int t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }

    b = a -b;
```

I just thought that both should work since they are doing the same.But it doesn't work.
Can anyone explain it please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if(b > a)` and `if(a > b)` are not "doing the same," as you put it.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `if ( b <= a )`.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). Then learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not the same: if you choose your second way, there is the chance that a always stays bigger then b. then you never get to svap variables, and b is always less then a after b=a-b, if b is positive

i think using

```
a=a-b
```

instead of

```
b=a-b
```

could do it